# MongoDB - count total / unique nested keys

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a document that contains this substructure in MongoDB, which lists the clothing items in my store, their type, and the specific sku to description mapping.

I want to answer the following questions:
- how many total types of clothing items do i have? 
- how many total skus do i have? unique skus?

How do I do this?

clothing_items

```
   shirts

      sku23 :  green with white stripes

   skirts

      sku0 : red 

      sku1 : gray

  .
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Problem is that if you have a unique key for every sku, this will be VERY hard. if you instead have lists for each sku with sku and color, you can do an `aggregation` function and increment a counter.

Comment: Also, could you post a sample document? It's unclear what exactly your documents look like as your sketch above isn't a valid document.